# Perform custom event before Session Expiry in Spring

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, session, spring-mvc

I am beginner in Spring framework.

In my case Session can be expire by following way
--> Success Log-out (Explicit Log-out )

--> Session Timeout (Implicit Log-out )

I  have do  DML(record insertion) in database whenever some user log in and I want to perform DML(record deletion) in database whenever user session timeout (Implicit Log-out).

My Question is that is there any way in Spring that  tell us before the expiry of session.
So I can do perform my custom event before session expiry.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Its dangerous.. what if you miss notification? What if your app goes down when user's session was active?

Comment: then what should I take next step?

Comment: that really depends on what record you store in DB and how important those records are..

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, you can do that with [SessionDestroyedEvent](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/3.2.5.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/session/SessionDestroyedEvent.html).

```
@Component
public class SessionEndedListener implements ApplicationListener<SessionDestroyedEvent> {

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(SessionDestroyedEvent event)
    {
        for (SecurityContext securityContext : event.getSecurityContexts())
        {
            Authentication authentication = securityContext.getAuthentication();
            YourPrincipalClass user = (YourPrincipalClass) authentication.getPrincipal();
            // do something
        }
    }

}
```

And in web.xml:

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher
    </listener-class>
</listener>
```

This event will be fired for both the regular logout as well as the session timeout.

Comment: What is that you wouldn't be able to do? Unless you hack the specific application server you are using you aren't able to get events before the fact, you get events during or after the fact.

Comment: Yes I got the solution @Codo your answer is helpful.

Comment: would i need 'Spring Security' component in my dependency if i am going with this approach. I had this question after seeing the Listener that needs to be registered.

Comment: I have a spring boot application and i implemented the SessionEndedListener as mentioned above to capture the SessionDestroyEvent. I didn't have to register the HttpSessionEventPublisher as a Listener, am just trying to understand how did it then work ?

Comment: this doesn't work me, do i have to use @EnableSpringHttpSession annotation or register the application listener somewhere? Do i need to enable sessionRepository for this?

Answer (score 4):

I have solved my problem by following way similar  @Codo answer

```
@Component
public class SessionCreatedListenerService implements ApplicationListener<ApplicationEvent> {

private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory
        .getLogger(SessionCreatedListenerService.class);

@Autowired
HttpSession httpSession;



@Override
public void onApplicationEvent(ApplicationEvent applicationEvent) {
    if(applicationEvent instanceof HttpSessionCreatedEvent){ //If event is a session created event



     }else if(applicationEvent instanceof HttpSessionDestroyedEvent){ //If event is a session destroy event
        // handler.expireCart();

         logger.debug(""+(Long)httpSession.getAttribute("userId"));

         logger.debug(" Session is destory  :" ); //log data

     }else if(applicationEvent instanceof AuthenticationSuccessEvent){ //If event is a session destroy event
         logger.debug("  athentication is success  :" ); //log data
     }else{
         /*logger.debug(" unknown event occur  : " Source: " + ); //log data
     }  
}   
}
```

Comment: during the Session Destroy event in my Spring Boot application, i am able to see the applicationEvent is only and instanceof SessionDestroyedEvent , instead of HttpSessionDestroyedEvent as mentioned in your solution. What difference is that ?

Comment: The `HttpSessionDestroyedEvent` is a direct subclass of `SessionDestroyedEvent ` as you can see in the docs at https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/3.2.5.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/session/HttpSessionDestroyedEvent.html

Answer (score 0):

```
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationListener;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.event.LogoutSuccessEvent;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component 

public class LogoutSuccessListener implements ApplicationListener<LogoutSuccessEvent>{

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(LogoutSuccessEvent evt) {
         String login = evt.getAuthentication().getName();
         System.out.println(login + " has just logged out");
    } 
}
```

Comment: Better to use LogoutSuccessEvent  . for me it's working fine and this is generalized solution