# Capture Spring Session Destroy Event without registering the HttpSessionEventPublisher Listener

Tags: spring, session, spring-session

I wanted to perform some clean-up activity during Spring Session destroy (logout and timeout) and tried following the solution provided at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27753111/perform-custom-event-before-session-expiry-in-spring/27753299#comment46186788_27753299) thread

but what made me curious is that, my application is a Spring Boot application and I didn't have to register the HttpSessionEventPublisher Listener , i just implemented the ApplicationListener interface and used the onApplicationEvent() method to capture the SessionDestroyEvent.

> My question is, How did my code work without registering this listener
>   ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is the answer from the Spring Session documentation itself

http://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/current/reference/html5/#api-redisoperationssessionrepository-sessiondestroyedevent

> > If you are using @EnableRedisHttpSession the SessionMessageListener and enabling the necessary Redis Keyspace events is done automatically. <<