# How to read session-timeout from spring controller

Tags: xml, spring, spring-mvc, session

How to read session-timeout from spring controller,
and i am Storing Login and Logout Information in Database.
When **session-timeout** called logout history was not storing into Database
Note : Here i am Not using Spring-Security

And session.setMaxInacTimeinterval not working

Comment: do you want set session timeout globally or on conditional basis?

Comment: i just want to store logout info into database when session expired my application not storing logout info when i am doing manual logout i am able to store login/logout info

Comment: one way of doing is listening for session destroy event. http://stackoverflow.com/a/27753299/410677. Any reason you should not have spring security dependency ?

Comment: No specific reason actually I just following Spring MVC Pattern only