# How to share login among two subdomains in java?

Tags: spring, session, spring-boot, spring-session

My strategy is the following.

`a.example.com` would store `session_id:user_id` in DB
and store `session_id` in cookie

`b.example.com` would read `session_id` in cookie and read `user_id` from DB and logs he in.

I'm having trouble when session expires in `a.example.com` there's no easy way to detect and delete `session_id:user_id` in DB.

There are some listeners I can use but they don't seem to send `expire` event right when session expires.

Is there a reliable way to delete `session_id:user_id` when session expires?

(`b.example.com` doesn't insert DB or create cookie, it doesn't have it's own login form)

Comment: I think you can use this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27753111/perform-custom-event-before-session-expiry-in-spring